# how python ROUND_HALF_EVEN works

Tags: python, math, floating-point, rounding

Why am i getting 0.27 as my answer for `round(0.265, 2)` even after my global context "rounding" is set to `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`?

Here is my code.

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal

print(decimal.getcontext())

a = 0.265
print(Decimal(a))
print(round(a, 2)) # current output: 0.27
```

Here is the output

```
Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999, capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow])
0.26500000000000001332267629550187848508358001708984375
0.27
```

I'm confused as i think output should be 0.26 instead on 0.27 since rounding is set to `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`.

Comment: `0.26500000000000001332267629550187848508358001708984375` is not halfway between 2.6 and 2.7. It's closer to 2.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0.26500000000000001332267629550187848508358001708984375` is a binary approximation of 0.265 and is closer to 0.27.

Try `a = Decimal('0.265')` to maintain precision.

From https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/round